# Converting Nanotime Object in R

Tags: r, nanotime

I need help with the following:
I am trying to convert a nanotime object in R such as:

```
x <- nanotime("2000-01-01T15:00:00.000000001+00:00")
```

into nanoseconds passed since January 1, 1970.
Is there an easy way to accomplish this?

Comment: I don't think the duplicate correctly addresses the question. Have you tried using `as.numeric(x)` ?

Comment: Thanks Ronah, as.numeric(x) did not work but It gave me the idea to try as.integer64(x) and that worked!